# How to interpret one variable but not another in a heredoc?

Tags: bash, heredoc

I want to interpret the first variable of this heredoc but not the other two variables. Is that possible?

```
cat << EOF >> "$__GREP_CACHE_FILE"

# (r) Recursively search pattern, (i) ignore case, (I) ignore binary files,
# (n) prefix with line number within file, (s) suppress error messages.
# Use path or current directory
function grepr() {
  # Usage: grepr PATTERN [PATH...]
  grep -rIins "$GREP_OPTIONS" '$1' '${2:-.}'
}
EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [@oguzismail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10248678/oguz-ismail)'s comment, you can escape the rest of the dollar signs:

```
cat << EOF >> "$__GREP_CACHE_FILE"

# (r) Recursively search pattern, (i) ignore case, (I) ignore binary files,
# (n) prefix with line number within file, (s) suppress error messages.
# Use path or current directory
function grepr() {
  # Usage: grepr PATTERN [PATH...]
  grep -rIins "\$GREP_OPTIONS" '\$1' '\${2:-.}'
}
EOF
```